# integration of bounded variation function is of bounded variation?

Tags: bounded-variation, total-variation

Let $g:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and define $f(x) = \int_{Y} g(x,y)\,dy$. Suppose that $g$ is of bounded variation, then can I say that $f(x)$ is also of bounded variation?

I have shown 
\begin{align*}
TV(f,X) = & \sup_p \sum_{i=0}^{n_p-1} |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|\\
        \le & \sup_p \sum_{i=0}^{n_p-1} \int_{Y}|g(x_{i+1},y)-g(x_{i},y)|\,dy\\
         \le &\text{I do not know how to proceed from here.}
\end{align*}

Comment: What does it mean to say that $(x,y) \mapsto g(x,y)$ has bounded variation?

Comment: @copper.hat $\sup_{\phi} \int_{X\times Y} g(x,y) d|\phi (x,y)|$ for $\phi$ is continuously iddferentiable on compact support and has sup norm less than 1?

Comment: Is the modulus right, around the $\phi$?